# Универсальный ipv6-адрес

Tags: javascript, ip, ipv6

При создании сервера на node.js в качестве hostname можно было указать `0.0.0.0`, чтобы к созданному серверу можно было обратиться по любому адресу. Какой адрес обладает аналогичным предназначением в протоколе ip v6?

```
const http = require('http');
const util = require('util');

function startServer(hostname, port) {
  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(util.format(new Date).replace(/[-:.]/g, '_'));
    console.log(req.method);
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);
    console.log(`handled by: ${hostname}`);
    console.log('===');

    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end(`hostname: ${hostname}\nport:     ${port}`);
  });

  server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Started:\nhostname: ${hostname}\nport:     ${port}\n===\n`);
  });
}

startServer('0.0.0.0', 8080); // Любой внешний адрес
startServer('::1', 8080);     // Только http://[::1]:8080/ и http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Ооооооом, `::` ?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, да! Спасибо! Ответом напишешь?

Comment: не, я не знаю как это развернуто написать, ибо не разбираюсь, просто погуглил. А ответ состоящий из двух двоеточий никому не полезен xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev, очень даже полезен - кратко и понятно :)

Comment: @MedvedevDev, кстати, а по какому запросу гуглил?

Comment: ipv6 0.0.0.0 equivalent

Comment: растянул ответ как смог xDDD

Comment: Хорошая догадка. Я ipv6 broadcast искал)

Comment: полезно иногда не знать контекст, а спрашивать "в лоб" xDDD

Comment: бродкаст - это другой тип адреса ;) вот и не нашел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

**IPv4:** `0.0.0.0` → **IPv6:** `::`